Maximal size of Sperner family that only contains small subsets
Let $[n]$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ and $2^{[n]}$ its power set.
A set $\mathcal{F}\subset 2^{[n]}$ of subsets of $[n]$ is called a sperner family if
for any distinct elements $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$, neither of them contains the other, i.e. $A\not\subset B,B\not\subset A$.
The size $\vert \mathcal{F}\vert$ of a Sperner family $\mathcal{F}$ is the number of subsets it contains. The famous theorem of Sperner gives the upper bound of $\vert \mathcal{F}\vert$:

Sperner's Theorem:
For every Sperner family $\mathcal{F}$ whose union has a total of $n$ elements, $\vert \mathcal{F}\vert\leq\binom{n}{[n/2]}$, equality holds if and only if $\mathcal{F}=\binom{[n]}{n/2}$ for $n$ even and $\mathcal{F}=\binom{[n]}{(n+1)/2}$ or $\mathcal{F}=\binom{[n]}{(n-1)/2}$ for $n$ odd.

Here $\binom{[n]}{k}$ denotes the set of all $k$-subset of $[n]$.
The theorem considers all sperner families over $2^{[n]}$. What if we consider those Sperner families only containing small elements ? That is,

Question: if $\mathcal{F}$ is a Sperner family consisting of subsets of $[n]$ with size no larger than $d$ and containing at least one $d-$element, $0<d<n$, then how large can $\vert \mathcal{F}\vert$ be?

I guess such $\mathcal{F}$ is just $\binom{[n]}{d}$ since it must contain at least one $d-$element.
I think this question has been proposed naturally but I didn't find references on the website.

This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797775/an-upper-bound-on-the-size-of-antichain/4798477#4798477

@MohammadAlhejji Thanks! That solves the case $d\leq[n/2]$.
